# Responsive image issue using Bootstrap

Tags: css, responsive-design

I Build slider but when i resize a browser i want my images center part not whole part or not left side part. how to do it ?

**CSS :**

```
.fill {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/*background-position: center;*/
/*-webkit-background-size: cover;*/
/*-moz-background-size: cover;*/
/*background-size: cover;*/
background-position: center center;
/*-o-background-size: cover;*/
background-color: transparent ;
}
```

Comment: We will need more than just a bunch css. Show us your html. Get us a JSFiddle.